# TypeError: create() got multiple values for keyword argument 'user'

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I'm sending post request from reactJS to Django rest to create post, but I'm getting this error.

TypeError: create() got multiple values for keyword argument 'user'

Everything is working fine except when i send user to project serializer. I'm saving my user in localstorage to get userId.
Please someone help me to solve this issue.

EDIT:
I have noticed that for some reason when i get userId from storage and storing it setState method, state is still null and serializer is receiving null value in user field.

This is my data formate
[image]

post.js

```
class PostProject extends Component {

    state = {
        controls: {
            title: {
                elementType: 'input',
                elementConfig: {
                    type: 'text',
                    placeholder: 'Cafe Management System'
                },
                value: ''
            },
            price: {
                elementType: 'input',
                elementConfig: {
                    type: 'text',
                    placeholder: '100'
                },
                value: ''
            },
            description: {
                elementType: 'input',
                elementConfig: {
                    type: 'text',
                    placeholder: 'Description about your project'
                },
                value: ''
            },
        },
        user: null,
        modules: [],
        technologies: [],
        requirements: [],
        tags: []
    };

    submitHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const user = localStorage.getItem('userId');
        this.setState({ user: user })
        //Get data from state
        for (let el = 0; el < this.props.modules.length; el++) {
            const obj = { project: this.state.controls.title.value, name: this.props.modules[el] }
            this.setState({
                modules: this.state.modules.push(obj)
            })
        }
        for (let el = 0; el < this.props.technologies.length; el++) {
            const obj = { project: this.state.controls.title.value, name: this.props.technologies[el] }
            this.setState({
                technologies: this.state.technologies.push(obj)
            })
        }
        for (let el = 0; el < this.props.requirements.length; el++) {
            const obj = { project: this.state.controls.title.value, name: this.props.requirements[el] }
            this.setState({
                requirements: this.state.requirements.push(obj)
            })
        }
        for (let el = 0; el < this.props.tags.length; el++) {
            const obj = { project: this.state.controls.title.value, title: this.props.tags[el] }
            this.setState({
                tags: this.state.tags.push(obj)
            })
        }
        const formData = {};
        for (let el in this.state.controls) {
            formData[el] = this.state.controls[el].value;
            formData['user'] = this.state.user;
            formData['modules'] = this.state.modules;
            formData['technologies'] = this.state.technologies;
            formData['requirements'] = this.state.requirements;
            formData['tags'] = this.state.tags;
        }
        console.log(formData);
        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/projects/', formData)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                alert('posted successfully');
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    };

    inputChangedHandler = (event, controlName) => {
        const updateControls = {
            ...this.state.controls,
            [controlName]: {
                ...this.state.controls[controlName],
                value: event.target.value,
            }
        };
        this.setState({ controls: updateControls });
    };

    render() {

        const fomElementArray = [];
        for (let key in this.state.controls) {
            fomElementArray.push({
                id: key,
                config: this.state.controls[key]
            });
        }

        let form = fomElementArray.map(formElemet => (
            <Input elementType={formElemet.config.elementType}
                elementConfig={formElemet.config.elementConfig}
                value={formElemet.config.value}
                key={formElemet.id}
                changed={(event) => this.inputChangedHandler(event, formElemet.id)} label={formElemet.config.elementConfig.placeholder} />
        ));
        return (
            <section className='container'>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 ">
                            <SecondaryHeading>Upload your project</SecondaryHeading><br />
                            <div className='border bg-white d-inline-block px-4 py-2 mb-5'>
                                <TertiaryHeading>Before you upload, make sure to read our terms.</TertiaryHeading>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Read the standards and requirements for item(s) you want to sell.</li>
                                    <li>Make sure your files are well organized.</li>
                                    <li>Always provide complete details about your project.</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <form >
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <TertiaryHeading>Name and Description</TertiaryHeading><br />
                                    <input type="text"
                                        className="form-control"
                                        name="title"
                                        placeholder="Name"
                                        onChange={(event) => this.inputChangedHandler(event, 'title')} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <textarea rows="8"
                                        className="form-control"
                                        name="description"
                                        placeholder="Write overview of your project..."
                                        onChange={(event) => this.inputChangedHandler(event, 'description')} ></textarea>

                                </div>
                            </form>
                            <hr />
                            <div className='mt-5'>
                                <TertiaryHeading>Features and Requirements</TertiaryHeading><br />
                                <div className="">
                                    <label htmlFor="description">Modules</label>
                                    <DynamicFieldSet btnLabel='Module' />
                                </div>
                                <div className="">
                                    <label htmlFor="description">Technologies</label>
                                    <DynamicFieldSet btnLabel='Technology' />
                                </div>
                                <div className="">
                                    <label htmlFor="description">Requirements</label>
                                    <DynamicFieldSet btnLabel='Requirement' />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <hr />

                            <div className='mt-5'>
                                <TertiaryHeading>Upload source files</TertiaryHeading><br />
                                <FileUpload />
                            </div>
                            <hr />

                            <div className='mt-5'>
                                <TertiaryHeading>Pricing</TertiaryHeading><br />
                                <input type="text"
                                    className="form-control col-md-2"
                                    name="title"
                                    placeholder="$5.00"
                                    onChange={(event) => this.inputChangedHandler(event, 'price')} />
                            </div>
                            <hr />
                            <div className='mt-5'>
                                <TertiaryHeading>Tags</TertiaryHeading><br />
                                <TagGroup />
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div className='col-md-4 mt-5'>
                            <TertiaryHeading>Choose Snapshots</TertiaryHeading><br />
                            <PicturesWall />
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div className="mt-5">
                        <p><span className="require">*</span> - required fields</p>
                    </div>
                    <form onSubmit={(event) => this.submitHandler(event)}>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <Button btnType="Btn-primary Btn-md ">Submit</Button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </section>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        modules: state.dynamicFormItemReducer.modules,
        technologies: state.dynamicFormItemReducer.technologies,
        requirements: state.dynamicFormItemReducer.requirements,
        tags: state.tagReducer.tags
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(PostProject);
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, post_save
from softforest.utils import unique_slug_generator

# Create your models here.

user = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL


class Project(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(user, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
    ratings = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=50, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    @property
    def modules(self):
        return self.module_set.all()


class Module(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='modules', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Technology(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='technologies', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Requirement(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='requirements', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


def project_pre_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = unique_slug_generator(instance)


pre_save.connect(project_pre_receiver, sender=Project)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Project, Module, Technology, Requirement
from tags.models import Tag
from accounts.models import User


class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for Project Tags"""

    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ('title',)


class RequirementSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for Project requirements"""

    class Meta:
        model = Requirement
        fields = ('name',)


class TechnologySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for Project technologies"""

    class Meta:
        model = Technology
        fields = ('name',)


class ModuleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for Project Modules"""
    print("MODULES SERIALIZER")

    class Meta:
        model = Module
        fields = ('name',)


class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for Project"""
    modules = ModuleSerializer(many=True)
    technologies = TechnologySerializer(many=True)
    requirements = RequirementSerializer(many=True)
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = [
            'id',
            'slug',
            'user',
            'title',
            'description',
            'price',
            'ratings',
            'modules',
            'technologies',
            'requirements',
            'tags'
            ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = validated_data['user']
        modules = validated_data.pop('modules')
        technologies = validated_data.pop('technologies')
        requirements = validated_data.pop('requirements')
        tags = validated_data.pop('tags')
        user_key = User.objects.filter(id__iexact=user)
        project = Project.objects.create(**validated_data, user=user_key)
        for module in modules:
            Module.objects.create(**module, project=project)
        for technology in technologies:
            Technology.objects.create(**technology, project=project)
        for requirement in requirements:
            Requirement.objects.create(**requirement, project=project)
        for tag in tags:
            Tag.objects.create(**tag, project=project)

        return project
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from .models import Project, Module
from drf_multiple_model.viewsets import ObjectMultipleModelAPIViewSet
from .serializers import ProjectSerializer, ModuleSerializer, TechnologySerializer, RequirementSerializer
from .models import *
from tags.models import Tag

# Create your views here.


class ProjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """A viewset for viewing and manipulating user instances"""

    print("PROJECT VIEWSET")
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'slug'
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, )

    @action(detail=True, methods=["GET"])
    def modules(self, request, id=None):
        project = self.get_object()
        modules = Module.objects.filter(project=project)
        serializer = ModuleSerializer(modules, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=200)

    @action(detail=True, methods=["GET"])
    def technologies(self, request, id=None):
        project = self.get_object()
        technologies = Technology.objects.filter(project=project)
        serializer = TechnologySerializer(technologies, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=200)

    @action(detail=True, methods=["GET"])
    def requirements(self, request, id=None):
        project = self.get_object()
        requirements = Requirement.objects.filter(project=project)
        serializer = RequirementSerializer(requirements, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=200)

    @action(detail=True, methods="POST")
    def project(self, request, id=None):
        print('POST')
        user = self.get_object()
        data = request.data
        print(data)
        data["user"] = user.id
        serializer = ProjectSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=201)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

Answer (score 0):

setState is asynchronous but you're treating it like it isn't. You need to change your submitHandler() method to something more like this. The second argument to setState() is where you should be doing all your manipulation because you're relying on this.state.user to exist, but simply calling setState({ user }); isn't waiting for it to actually occur...

```
this.setState({ user: user },
  () => {
    for (let el = 0; e...
  }
);
```

Before this I would probably move all that extra code after the setState() call to it's own function:

```
this.setState({ user }, () => doExtraWork());
```

Then all your for loops and other setState() calls are neatly put into doExtraWork(). This should ensure that this.state.user exists and your code can work.

The second problem you have is that you did this in four places:

```
this.setState({
  tags: this.state.tags.push(obj)
})
```

This isn't going to work. Take the tags out into a variable, add what you want, then use setState() properly ie this.setState({ tags }).